# What is the XPATH of these table rows on this page? I can't figure it out!

Tags: xpath, screen-scraping

I've never had such a mission scraping a web page as I do with this specific one. I am trying to parse the reviews from Omgili's API results page. An example page is located here:

[Omgili](http://omgili.com/reviews/929DEA4D599E58A462641D0459629382%24885909112432%240BE2883391F41B836F976B1ED2BE1A48%248285A99C0EE8646F7C4E84B595C61AE7%24C1B92C9CCA427C325E734FB9D4566509%2436486076/Apple-iPod-Nano-2nd-Generation-Silver-%282-GB%29-MP3-Player)

I have scraped lots of pages before, but the exact XPATH of the results of this page is really tricky, since there are no DIV class names, and there are like 5 nested tables. I would like XPath that returns all of the table rows for each result (e.g. the first result would be the TR that contains the first review: "Does exactly what it needs to do - [03 Feb 2010] " and its content.

Any help for this, or at least point me to a resource that can help? I have tried CHrome selector gadget, but not even this works for this site.

I have tried the following currently, but this fails:     `//table//table//tr[4]//table/tr/td[1]/table/tr`

Comment: have you tried looking for FF add-ons? https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1095/ there are more XPATH addons (like Firefinder for Firebug)

Comment: THat worked, thanks! This is the shittiest xpath I'ver ever seen, but it works:

/html/body/form/table//tr/td/table//tr[4]/td/table//tr/td[1]/table//tr[position()>1]

Comment: I don't think XPath is the right tool for the job.  The HTML is entirely too messy:  http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://omgili.com/reviews/929DEA4D599E58A462641D0459629382$885909112432$0BE2883391F41B836F976B1ED2BE1A48$8285A99C0EE8646F7C4E84B595C61AE7$C1B92C9CCA427C325E734FB9D4566509$36486076/Apple-iPod-Nano-2nd-Generation-Silver-(2-GB)-MP3-Player&charset=(detect+automatically)&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be tempted to cheat (if it works!) and note that the *review* links are the only links on that page with targets that start `jmp`. So

```
//tr[td/span/a[starts-with(@href, 'jmp')]]
```

should be the rows you want.

Answer (score 0):

How about this query:

```
//form [Name='f']//table[2]//table[3]//table/tr
```

Well, I translated it from HTQL using iRobotSoft Web Scraper:

```
<form (Name='f')>1.<table>2.<table>3.<table>1.<tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works as well (after [AakashM's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144718/what-is-the-xpath-of-these-table-rows-on-this-page-i-cant-figure-it-out/4145003#4145003)):

`//a[starts-with(@href, '/jmp')]/ancestor::tr[1]`